# Filtering Dashboard at run time based on account

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, custom

How can I run a dashboard, for example, filtered on account number at run time so that I show only the records based on a specific account number at run time? I am able to build a report that can be filtered by account at runtime and I am able to build a filtered dashboard, I thought it would be as straightforward as creating a custom link with the salesforceid of the dashboard and pass it in the the account.id of the account record that I am on but I do not get expected results when I test the link from the account page.

Answer (score 1):

Dashboards can only filter by user/role (using Dynamic Dashboards) or by a specific user (using a static dashboard).

However, you *can* build a dashboard that supports dynamic filtering. In fact, I wrote one up just for the purpose of this demo. Please not that, for all intents and purposes, it will work on all modern browsers (even, amazingly, IE8, which isn't even modern). Browsers not supported by salesforce probably won't support this code.

First, you need some Visualforce pages. We'll start with a simple account lookup page controller:

```
public class accountLookup {
    public Contact contact { get; set; }

    public accountLookup() {
        contact = new Contact();
    }
}
```

And the corresponding page:

```
<apex:page controller="accountLookup">
    <script>
        function notify() {
            var a = document.querySelector('#accountid').value;
            window.sessionStorage.setItem('accountid', a);
        }

        function init() {
            var a = window.sessionStorage.getItem('accountid');
            if(a) {
                updatepage(a);
            }
        }

        window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
    </script>
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:actionRegion>
        <apex:actionFunction name="updatepage" reRender="form">
            <apex:param name="accountid" assignTo="{!contact.accountid}" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>
        </apex:actionRegion>
        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.accountid}">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="form" oncomplete="notify()"/>
        </apex:inputField>
        <input type="hidden" id="accountid" value="{!Contact.AccountId}" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Next, we'll set a page that shows a list of opportunities, first with a controller:

```
public class showOpps {
    public string accountId { get; set; }
    public account account { get; set; }
    public Opportunity[] opportunitylist { get; set; }

    public void rerender() {
        opportunitylist = new opportunity[0];
        account = new Account(name='-- none --');
        if(String.isNotBlank(accountId)) {
            opportunitylist = [select id, name, amount, closedate from opportunity where accountid = :accountId];
            Account = [select id, name from account where id = :accountid];
        }        
    }
}
```

And, of course, the page to render the data:

```
<apex:page controller="showOpps">
    <script>
    function handlestorage(event) {
        updatepage(event.newValue);

    }

    function init() {
        var a = window.sessionStorage.getItem('accountid');
        if(a) {
            updatepage(a);
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('storage', handlestorage, false);
    window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
    </script>
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:actionFunction reRender="form" name="updatepage" action="{!rerender}">
            <apex:param name="accountId" assignTo="{!accountId}" value=""/>
        </apex:actionFunction>
        {!Account.Name}
        <apex:dataTable value="{!opportunitylist}" var="opp">
            <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!opp.name}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Amount" value="{!opp.amount}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Close Date" value="{!opp.closedate}"/>
        </apex:dataTable>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Please note that this is very crude code. I cobbled it together for demonstration purposes.

Here's how it works:

First, we add the lookup page to a dashboard component. For simplicity, this page remembers the last account you used to filter by for the session (if you close the browser and try it again, it'll start fresh). You could set this in a persistent cookie or localStorage, but that's outside the scope of this demo.

Next, we wire up the page so that when the lookup value changes, we'll store the data in sessionStorage. All of your Visualforce pages in any tab, window, or iframe, that belong to the same namespace, will be able to see this data.

After that, we add the component that shows the data. For simplicity, it again loads data from storage when it loads, in case the value was set earlier and we missed it, etc. It listens for storage changes, and when a change occurs, it rerenders its output area with data from that account.

Of course, I could have used a Visualforce chart, Fusion chart, Google chart, or almost any other kind of chart, but that's again outside the scope of this answer. Even if you have many components, each using a Visualforce page, it should load okay on modern browsers.

Final note, you may have some cross-browser issues with IE 8 (it still requires attachEvent?), but you can sort those out pretty easily with the information available about cross-browser support.